# LayoutInflater or View creation programmatically

Tags: android, android-view, layout-inflater, performance

Is it faster to define a `Vie`w in a xml layout file and use it via `LayoutInflater` in the application or is it faster to define it within the program? I understand that it is "cleaner" to define the `View` via xml yet here I am just interested in the performance aspect. (I am writing an adapter which uses heaps of views of a very simple type)

Comment: It would be a *bit* (probably) faster to create it in code as the `LayoutInflater` will do some extra work to construct the `View` from the layout resource(getting the layout, parsing it etc). In the end this isn't something that should really interest you, there will not be any real performance gain from using one or the other of the methods.

Comment: thx Luksprog, not a question of major importance I agree, both should just do okay. The reason I ask is that I am in the process of getting familiar with android right now and want to establish some habits how to handle things ...

Comment: Use the layouts file when possible, they are the recommended way.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your need if you do it programmatically it will little bit fast as it save xml parsing time  but if you want a complex relative view it is better to use xml as  then there would be no time saving as you have to add many lines of complex code to do so which could be done very easily through xml  .

Comment: Thx - as mentioned, "views of a very simple typ". Still i am wondering if the layout approach might be faster as this is partly not happening at runtime i guess.